# Run a APScheduler task in a django_tenant backend not working

Tags: django, cron, apscheduler

I have a Django-multi-tenant SaaS running in Django with Ubuntu 18.04.

I'm using APscheduler to run schedule tasks for user online verification, in the Public Schema, everything works very well.

But the schedule is not starting in the subsequent schemas.

Anyone have any solution for it ?

BR

Comment: Have you got solution I am looking same